# Can anyone suggest a program like OneNote, but with more database-like features?

Tags: database, microsoft-onenote

I'm trying to use Microsoft Onenote 2010 to organise and create notes for a PhD and it has many advantages, but I'm finding the limitations of the format frustrating.

For example, the functionality for creating a page to a certain template etc. works very nicely for creating a notebook page for each academic paper I read, listing a few properties and then my typed / written notes on it and links to similar content etc. Onenote is very useful for being unconstrained as to how much and what type of information I include in the paper's page, along with that information being formattable for visual impact.

However, if I want to organise the pages for my papers by date, I cannot. I can't give a page properties other than to have it include certain information. Ideally I would be able to tell the page to have the property 'Date' with the value '10/09/2013' or whatever, the property 'Author' with value 'L Keal' and have all of this information searchable and sortable, maybe displayed in a main table.

Is there any program that can offer this middle ground between the ease of note-taking software and a database?

Comment: There are a number of addons/extensions for OneNote that have been written against its API. Certainly page sorting is amongst them (no ideas if only by title, which wouldn't meet your requirements, or more flexible).

Comment: Have you looked into Evernote?

Answer (score 1):

See if our app Obvibase works for you. It may or may not work for your specific use-case, but it matches exactly the description "middle ground between the ease of note-taking software and a database".

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/obvibase/hoddinokjifhganfcgkjmkkngljebjdj - installable Chrome App that enables better copy/paste.

https://www.obvibase.com - for browsers other than Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`Evernote` is better `Onenote` use it instead.

http://evernote.com/

---

You can also try these too:

http://www.treepad.com/treepadfreeware/

http://debriefnotes.com/

Comment: You did not answer OP's question about database-like requirements. I'm downvoting until corrected. It should be also said that Evernote has relatively low limit for free storage. You hit it soon especially if you sometimes store images. Then you must upgrade to subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.connectedtext.com/

it is a personal wiki software and has many features that allow you to organize your notes in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combo of EndNote (citation software where I could keep all notes on reading in a searchable/sortable way and automate all citation and bibliography) and Scrivener (database writing software that exports easily to word, where I could keep all composition, notes, and fieldnotes in a searchable, sortable way, and it works with EndNote).